# Codeigniter form validation callback function issue

Tags: validation, callback, codeigniter-3

I have a form with one input field name="uid" type="text"
a table 'tbl_users' and there is a column 'uid'
I want to validate $this->input->post('uid') if it is already in the database column. codes are given bellow:-

Controller/File1.php 
--in validate_data()

```
$this->load->model('model1');
$data['validation_result'] = $this->model1->validate_data();
$this->load->view('view1');
```

Model/model1.php

```
public $set_of_rules = [
  'item1'=>[
    'field'=>'uid',
    'label'=>'User ID',
    'rules'=>'trim|required|callback_validateUID',
    'field'=>'uid',
    'errors'=>[
       'required'=>'uid must be filled in',
       'validateUID'=>'UID does not exist, please input valid UID',
     ],
  ],
];
public validate_data()
{
$this->form_validation->set_rules($this->set_of_rules);
if(!$this->form_validation->run())
   return validation_errors() ;
}
else
{
   /*$this->db->do_some_database_tasks */
   return 'success' ;
}
public validateUID()
{
   var_dump('UID validation started...');
   $uid = $this->input->post('uid');
   $result = $this->db->where(['uid'=>$uid])->get('tbl_users')->row();
   if($result!=NULL) return TRUE;
   else return FALSE;
}
```

Problem is, validation rule 'callback_validateUID' does not executed [because I've put a script in it so that I can understand that validation has run the callback function] but the validation error message ('UID does not exist, please input valid UID') is shown, even though if I leave the input field blank, 'required' is not checkes !

could anyone please help?

Comment: $this->form_validation->set_rules('uid', 'User id', 'required'); insted of $this->form_validation->set_rules($this->set_of_rules);

Comment: actually there will be some other rules also...
so I don't want change setting the set of rules in an array,
and It's the same thing in fact...

Comment: ok can you tried my ans

Answer (score 0):

try this in model

```
   function SetofRules() {
   $rules = array(
      array('field'=>'uid', 'label'=>'User', 'rules'=>'trim|required'),
      array('field'=>'password', 'label'=>'Password', 'rules'=>'trim|required'),
   );


    $this->load->library('form_validation');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

   $errors = array();
   if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
      foreach ($rules as $r)
         $errors[$r['field']] = $this->form_validation->error($r['field']);
          if (!$errors['uid'])
      if ($this->userPrefix( $this->input->post('uid'), 'uid'))
         $error['uid'] = $this->form_validation->error('uid');
         if (!empty($errors)) return $errors;
   else return false;
   }
```